# Retonar uma lista sem os repetidos

Tags: haskell

**Definir uma função recursiva primitiva capaz de comprimir a lista removendo
todos os elementos repetidos em sequencia.
Ex : aaabbbcddd → abcd**

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso? Sinceramente não sei por onde começar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estou a assumir que este é o output que desejas.

- aaabbbcddd → abcd
- aaabbbaaacddd → abacd

Para isso podes tentar algo do género.

**Versão 1:**

```
removeDups :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
removeDups []             =  []
removeDups (xs : [])      =  [xs]
removeDups (x1:x2:xs)
          | x1 == x2     =      removeDups (x2 : xs)
          | otherwise    = x1 : removeDups (x2 : xs)
```

Os seguintes casos são triviais.

```
removeDups []             =  []    -- Lista vazia
removeDups (xs : [])      =  [xs]  -- Lista apenas com um elemento
```

A lógica para os outros casos é a seguinte:

- Se dois elementos adjacentes são iguais então salta o primeiro dos dois elementos e avalia de forma recursiva o resto da lista até encontrar dois elementos diferentes ou encontrar um dos casos triviais.
- Caso sejam diferentes então inclui o primeiro elemento na lista resultado e avalia o resto da lista de forma recursiva.

**Versão 2:**

Alternativa que usa apenas funções pré-definidas

```
removeDups :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
removeDups= map head . group
```

Esta versão usa a função `group` que recebe como parâmetro uma lista e devolve uma lista de listas em que cada uma das sub-listas é composta apenas por elementos iguais.

Função [group](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#g:10)

```
group "Mississippi" = ["M","i","ss","i","ss","i","pp","i"]
```

Depois é simples, aplicas a função `head` a cada uma das sublistas para devolver apenas o primeiro elemento.

Caso desejes obter uma lista sem elementos repetidos:

- aaabbbaaacddd → abcd

Então basta ordenar a lista (usando a função `sort`) antes de executares a função `removeDups`.

Answer (score 3):

Já faz um certo tempo que foi perguntado, mas aí vai a minha implementação.

```
removeDup :: String -> String
removeDup []     = []
removeDup [a]    = [a]
removeDup (x:xs) = x:(removeDup $ filter (/=x) xs)
```

Basicamente a mágica acontece quando o filter remove os elementos **x** de **xs**

```
removeDup "abacabc"
-- 1º passo => 'a' : "bcbc"
-- 2º passo => 'a' : 'b' : "cc"
-- 3º passo => 'a' : 'b' : 'c' : [] == "abc"
```

Comment: Resolve o problema, mas veja que é uma implementação quadrática (O(n^2)), para cada elemento você percorre a lista toda olhando se ele não está lá, praticamente um bubble sort da remoção de duplicatas (mas vai um upvote pela simplicidade da função).

Comment: Verdade, mas me parece que não tem muito o que fazer. O nub (método que faz a mesma coisa) do Data.List faz algo muito parecido. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#nub